# How to indicate success via alert dialog?

Tags: android, user-interface, android-alertdialog

I'm hoping this question isn't too open ended. I'm trying to figure out the simplest way to do a particular bit of functionality in my program. Without going into too much detail about the program itself, what happens at the point in question is that an alert dialog pops up and once the user hits "Okay" on the dialog, a string gets written out to a file. In the method I wrote that does this, it indicates success or failure via a boolean. I am trying to figure out how I can indicate to the user if it was successful or not without having to make a whole other alert dialog but I'm not sure how to go about it. Can I just change the message text on the previous one and if I can then how do I go about making it stay long enough for the user to read it and then disappear either through user input or on its own? If I'm not being clear enough here I'll edit my question. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: show message in Toast instead

Comment: How about using a `Toast`. They are subtle and informative.

Comment: Thank you both. I'll do just that. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a Toast message. Even If you want you can create your custom design for Toast. See [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html) for details

Answer (score 2):

Best approach is to just use a `Toast`. You can change the text in dialogs but it does not make sense for this application. Using a `Toast` of your boolean flag is easy.

```
if(yourBooleanFlagIsTrue){
    Toast.makeText(context, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} else {
    Toast.makeText(context, "Failure", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

context in the code above will change depending on where you are using the `Toast`. For example, if its within a fragment you will have to use `getActivity()`. If its within an `activity` you can use `getApplicationContext()`.

Comment: Thank you much. I don't know why I didn't think of doing that myself. Probably just been looking at the same bit of code too long. >_<